Error phpstan.neon: Bad indentation on line 3, column 5
I created a .neon file from the documentation.
https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols
I put the .neon file in the project root folder where I am running the phpstan command from. I added these lines.
parameters:
   level: 0
   scanDirectories:
          - src
          - library
          - interface

This is the command that I am executing from the CLI
php vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon interface/patient_file/report

I have copied and pasted the example from the documentation to get the format corrected and still get the error message about the indentions.

What error message? Where is the symbol you’re trying to discover found?

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. It could also help to use a better title, that describes your problem
